# Why does JQuery creates redundant <p></p> elements with this html string?

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried it with both `append` and `html` in JQuery, but both methods produce a pair of empty `<p></p>` before and after the `<table>` element, given this string:

```
'<p>Blah blah my table below:</p><p><table><thead><tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>H</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>P</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>H</td><td>A</td></tr></tbody></table></p>'
```

You can see this by inspecting elements in the results panel of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KCrrV/.

Where does these empty `<p></p>` come from?

Comment: Maybe it's the mechnasim in jquery, and you hit that.

Comment: @CharlieShi What mechanism are you talking about? The markup is invalid.

Comment: @undefined i think jQuery does make some magic and confused  CharlieShi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` can not be inside `p` tags .

So you get `empty p` tags at top and bottom

Example

```
<p> // Browser makes it <p></p>
<table>.....</table>
</p> // Browser makes it <p></p>
```

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1